# Partial failure in HANA import

Tags: csv, import, hana

I am importing data from CSV files into HANA using control files and it has been working fine initially. But now when I try to import I see the error message

> java.sql.SQLWarning: some of rows have failed to be imported:
> Partial failure occurs in importing /pathToMyFile.ctl

But this error is not coming always. Sometimes the upload is successful and sometimes it is not with the same control file. My code to import is

```
ALTER TABLE “SCHEMA”.”TABLE” DISABLE AUTOMERGE;

IMPORT FROM ‘/sapmnt/log/test.ctl’ WITH THREADS 120 BATCH 200000;

MERGE DELTA OF “SCHEMA”.”TABLE”;
```

When I see the error file it shows

> transaction rollbacked by internal error TrexUpdate failed on table
> “SCHEMA”.”TABLE” with error attributeload failed
> ;index=SCHEMA:*SYS_SPLIT*”TABLE” attribut="id"

The index server trace file:

```
258744 [thr=24526]: Pool ls Inactive 
259045 [thr=24527]: IndexingQueue is inactive
302032 [thr=25528]: sq1Executor is inactive 
22908105 [thr=22493]: JobWrk10577 is inactive 
873639 [thr=24531]: SqlExecutor is inactive
878555 [thr=24536]: Pool is inactive 
885442 [thr=25537]: SqlExecutor is inactive 
1121929 [thr=25706]: GroupMulticastExecutor(MasterPo is inactive
1121932 [thr=25707]: GroupMulticastExecutor(MasterPo is inactive
54977 [thr=24502]: SqlExecutor is inactive 
54980 [thr=24503]: SqlExecutor is inactive 
54983 [thr=24504]: SqlExecutor is inactive
54986 [thr=24505]: SqlExecutor is inactive
54990 [thr=24506]: SqlExecutor is inactive
54993 [thr=24507]: SqlExecutor is inactive
54996 [thr=24508]: SqlExecutor is inactive
55000 [thr=24509]: SqlExecutor is inactive
55003 [thr=24510]: MergedogMonitor is inactive 
55008 [thr=24511]: Request is inactive 
55011 [thr=24512]: Request is inactive 
55014 [thr=24514]: EpochConununicator is inactive
55017 [thr=24513]: Request is inactive 
55022 [thr=24515]: SqlListener is inactive
```

Original screenshot of index server trace file:

[image]

Comment: What you describe sounds a bit like a HANA bug. Try some storage repair and see if it fixes it: `ALTER SYSTEM RECLAIM DATA SPACE`and `CALL CHECK_CATALOG('CHECK', NULL, NULL, NULL);`

Comment: the RECLAIM DATA SPACE and the mentioned error have nothing to do with each other as the partitioning works on a completely different internal level than the persistence space management. Checking the DB catalog is never a bad idea, but wouldn't help much either.

Comment: @John: please provide the definition of your table and the error message from the indexserver tracefile. Since the error says, that loading the partitioned column ID failed, I suspect that there might be an out of memory error or something like that.

Comment: @Lars.Br I added the trace file image.

Comment: @Lars.Br I don't think it is because of OOM because I unloaded all the tables and imported a very small table(900 kb CSV file) but then also the above error appeared